# Rounded corner div for active list item

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I have the below html structure to which I apply rounded corners using images.
The divs with classes tabsLeft and tabsRight implement the round corners. 
Once an li is selected, I am adding the class 'on' to it. When the first li has .on class, the color of the left corner should also change.
Is there a css only solution to change the image of the tabsLeft class when the first li is on?I cannot put the tabsLeft left inside any li, because not all list items are visible to every user (any list item can be the first one).

```
<div>
<div class="tabsLeft"></div>
<ul class="tabs" id="tabList" runat="server">
   <li id="a" class="on" runat="server"></li>        
   <li id="b" runat="server"></li>        
   <li id="c" runat="server"></li>        
   <li id="d" runat="server"></li>                      
</ul>
<div class="tabsRight"></div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.tabsLeft{background: url('/Home/images/New.PNG') -256px 0px no-repeat; width: 3px;height: 30px;float: left;position: absolute;}

.tabsRight{background: url('/Home/images/New.PNG') -263px 0px no-repeat;width: 3px;height: 30px;right: 0px;}
```

Css i want on first active tab -

```
{background: url('/Home/images/New.PNG') -248px 0px no-repeat; width: 3px;height: 30px;float: left;position: absolute;}
```

Comment: I have posted the css i need. Css contents are not the issue. I need a proper selector to apply for third css class.

Comment: use Jquery for active tab

Comment: And if u want only Rounded Corner set The Border-radius:10px;.

Comment: Thanks! So this cannot be done using css only :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change a child's CSS based on the class status of a parent, but you can't change a parent's CSS based on the class status of a child. And you cannot change the the CSS of an element based on the class status of a completely unrelated element.

But, what you might try in your case is to put the background on the first `LI` itself. You can then modify that based on its own class status:

```
.tabs > li:first-child { background: url('/Home/images/New.PNG') -256px 0px no-repeat; etc... }
.tabs > li.on:first-child { background-position: -248px 0px; }
```

(obviously you'll need to play with the styles to make it work for your case)